# NameError. Function definition not getting read in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to run a basic app on Google App Engine using Python. The code asks for user inputs and validates them. I can't seem to get the following code to run:

```
import webapp2
import re
import cgi

def escape_html(s):
    return cgi.escape(s, quote = True)

USER_RE = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20}$")
def valid_username(username):
    return USER_RE.match(username)

EMAIL_RE = re.compile(r'^[\S]+@[\S]+\.[\S]+$')
def valid_email(email):  
    return EMAIL_RE.match(email)

PASS_RE = re.compile(r"^.{3,20}$")
def valid_pass(password):   
    return PASS_RE.match(password)

form = """  #form is an HTML form that asks for Username, Pass and Email.
<form method="post">
    <br> <label> Username </label> <input type="text" name="username" value= %(username)s> <div style="color: red">%(error1)s</div><br>
    <label> Password </label> <input type="password" name="password"> <div style="color: red">%(error3)s</div><br>
    <label> Verify Password </label> <input type="password" name="verify"> <div style="color: red">%(error4)s</div> <div style="color: red">%(error5)s</div><br>
    <label> Email </label> <input type="text" name="email" value= %(email)s> <div style="color: red"> %(error2)s </div><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit Form">
</form>
"""


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write_form(self,error1="",error2="",error3="",error4="" , error5="", username="",email="" ):
        self.response.out.write(form %{"error1":error1, "error2":error2,"error3":error3,"error4":error4,    "error5":error5,"username":escape_html(username),"email":escape_html(email)})

    def get(self):
        self.write_form()


    def post(self):
        usr_username = self.request.get("username")
        usr_email = self.request.get("email")
        usr_password = self.request.get("password")
        usr_verify = self.request.get("verify") 
        error1="";error2="";error3="";error4="";error5="";

        username = vaild_username(usr_username);
        email = vaild_email(usr_email);
        password = vaild_pass(usr_password);
        verify = vaild_pass(usr_verify);

        if not (sername):  
            error1 = "That is not a valid username"
        if not (email):  
            error2 = "That is not a valid email"
        if not (password):
            error3 = "That is not a valid password"
        if not (verify):
            error4 = "That is not a valid verify password"
        if (password != verify):
            error5 = "Passwords not matching!"

        self.write_form(error1, error2, error3, error4, error5, usr_username, usr_email)
        if (username and password and email and verify and password==verify):
            self.redirect("/thanks" )



class ThanksHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        username = self.request.get("username")
        self.response.out.write("Welcome" + username)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                              ('/thanks', ThanksHandler)],
                             debug=True)
```

I am getting a Nameerror global name 'valid_username' is not defined (Line 62). This is strange because the function definitions are already at the top of the file. I think Python is not reading the three validation functions at the top for some reason. I have checked for misspellings and indentation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't check for misspellings enough: your code says:

```
username = vaild_username(usr_username);
```

"vaild" is something else than "valid" :-)

And: you don't need a semicolon at the end of a line.

Comment: all the methods are spelled incorrectly not just vaild_username and     `if not (sername):` should be    `if not (username):`

Comment: Yeah. "I have checked for misspellings and indentation errors" is kinda far-fetched :-)

Comment: Yes that is slightly inaccurate :-)